# AJAX .responseText want to assign to global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For CORS AJAX request, the best and cross browser supported example is the following one as I know...

http://saltybeagle.com/2009/09/cross-origin-resource-sharing-demo/

The above one working as properly but callback return only local variable not global. Can somebody give me the idea how to make global variable return from AJAX callback.

In jQuery code, if I would like to return global variable result I can do as follow:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    url: url,
    success: function(data){
        result = data;
    },
    error: function(xhr){
        alert("Request cannot complete");
    },
    async: false
}).responseText;
```

But above jQuery.ajax() POST example is not fully support by IE.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What "local variable" do you need to promote to global scope?

Comment: In the example page given in above, did you see postCORS() function is return data variable? What exactly I want to do is, I would like to return global variable result from that function.

Comment: You should not use synchronous requests. And you should not need a global variable, then.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, couldn't you just assign the result to a previously declared global variable?

Comment: @Bergi can you tell me why "I should not use synchronous requests. And Ishould not need a global variable?" in some case requirement is different as I know. Isn't it?

Comment: You know the drawbacks of synchronous requests? They can easily freeze the browser. If you have a really good reason for using them nonetheless, I'd like to hear about it :-)